# Regarding try-catch

Tags: java, exception, if-statement, try-catch, throw

I am currently taking a introductory course in Java and   this is regarding try-catch method. When I type this my `System.out.println` statement keeps repeating endlessly. Here is my code:

```
public static double exp(double b, int c) {
    if (c == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    // c > 0
    if (c % 2 == 0) {
        return exp(b*b, c / 2);
    }
    if (c<0){
        try{
        throw new ArithmeticException();
        }
        catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("yadonegoofed");
        }
    }

    // c is odd and > 0
    return b * exp(b, c-1);
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question here. Please expand :-)

Comment: Apart form the particular problem: Throwing an exception and catching it immediatly is not a good use of exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (c<0){
    try{
    throw new ArithmeticException();
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println("yadonegoofed");
    }
}

// c is odd and > 0
return b * exp(b, c-1);
```

Your comment `c is odd and > 0` is incorrect -- you never actually *terminated* the function with the exception. You threw it, you immediately caught it, and then continued to execute the recursive function. Eventually, when you hit [wraparound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), it'll be a positive number again, and the errors won't happen. (It's about two billion iterations away -- don't wait.)

I would not use an exception here -- you just need to terminate the recursion. I'd check for negative input *before* checking for `0`, and throw the exception there, and *catch the exception in the caller*.

In pseudo-code:

```
exp(double b, int c) {
    if (c < 0)
        throw new Exception("C cannot be negative");
    } else if (c % 2 == 0) {
        return exp(b*b, c / 2);
    } else {
        /* and so forth */
    }
}
```

Comment: You explain it far better than I did below.  To be fair, if having a negative c truly is an exceptional situation (i.e. c should never be < 0), it may be sensible to throw - but you certainly shouldn't be catching the exception you just threw.

Comment: @James: agreed, catching the exception immediately is _very_ strange. I have seen exceptions used to exit deeply-nested loops before, but it is _odd_ practice for a method to catch an exception it throws.

Comment: and looking back at the code, it's only valid for positive integers, so it makes sense to throw, but it should definitely be propagating it, not catching.

Comment: it's still odd to use there.  I'd think a labeled continue would be more appropriate.

Comment: I think throwing an exception is fair game -- since this function is only valid for non-negative inputs, any caller that calls it with a non-negative input is, by definition, broken.

Comment: Indeed.  I called this out elsewhere after re-reading the code.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot one very important part when it comes to creating your own custom exceptions. You forgot to tell the method that it will throw such a method. 
Your first line of code should look like this:

```
public static double exp(double b, int c) throws ArithmeticException {
```

Note that I have tested this myself, and it will only throw the exception one time in your output.

Comment: This method also catches the exception -- it can't leave the function. It's a good point though, once the problem is fixed. :)

Answer (score 1):

If for example, c = -1 in, the first and second if fails, the third if throws an exception and then prints the error, but things progress because you handled the excpetion. So it calls exp(b, -2).  In turn, that calls exp(b, -3) in the return, and so on.  Add the value of C to your println to verify.

Comment: I especially like the suggestion _Add the value of C to your `println` to verify._. That will point out the problem _very_ quickly. :)

Comment: @sarnold - my general principle of throwing exceptions - if it's truly an exceptional case, and you can't tell why it's exceptional from the message, you're doing it wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, right at the end you have `return b * exp(b, c-1);` this is going to call `exp` again which will call it again.
So the function will keep repeating and so will
`System.out.println`.

Answer (score 0):

Your BASE case is VERY specific...what in your code GUARANTEES that c will equal 0?  Currently, this is the ONLY way that you exit your recursive call.  As @Jay said you always subtract 1 which causes the thrown exception, but c is already below 0 at that point so it doesn't EQUAL 0.  Change your first `if` statement to catch values <= 0 and you should be fine.

```
if( c <= 0 )
     return 1;
```

Comment: While I think you hit this quite well, the case that `c < 0` is probably an _error_, and should be handled as an error.

Comment: @sarnold while this may be true. there is no actual questions so everyone is simply speculating as to what the expected result is... The only thing he seems to mention is a problem is that the sys.out always prints.  I simply stated a way to solve that.  Again, with the info given all any of us can do is speculate.